# How can I retrieve a child property using @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, json

I have the following metadata for the artist Joseph Turner:

```
{
    "activePlaceCount":0,
    "birth":{
        "place":{
            "name":"London, United Kingdom",
            "placeName":"London",
            "placeType":"inhabited_place"
         },
        "time":{
            "startYear":1775
        }
    },
    "birthYear":1775,
    "date":"1775\u20131851",
    "death":{
        "place":{
            "name":"Chelsea, United Kingdom",
            "placeName":"Chelsea",
            "placeType":"neighbourhood"
        },
        "time":{
            "startYear":1851
        }
    },
    "fc":"Joseph Mallord William Turner",
    "gender":"Male",
    "id":558,
    "mda":"Turner, Joseph Mallord William",
    "movements":[
        {
            "era":{
                "id":290,
                "name":"18th century"
            },
            "id":345,
            "name":"Picturesque"
        },
        {
            "era":{
                "id":350,
                "name":"19th century"
            },
            "id":364,
            "name":"Romanticism"
        },
        {
            "era":{
                "id":290,
                "name":"18th century"
            },
            "id":349,
            "name":"Sublime"
        }
    ],
    "startLetter":"T",
    "totalWorks":41861,
    "url":"http://www.tate.org.uk/art/artists/joseph-mallord-william-turner-558"
}
```

If I wanted to map `fc` to `firstName` in my Java program, I could simply do the following:

```
@JsonProperty("fc")
private String fullName;
```

That, or `private String fc`.

What would I do if wanted to retrieve `"death"."time"."startYear"`?

Comment: Not (easily) with jackson objectmapper but you could use different libraries especially if you're interested in just reading json: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17921582), it is currently not possible to create an annotation of this sort, but it is a ticket for the future (updates of Java).